# Image animation problems in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I state that I am not very experienced in Unity.
I am working on a project in which I have some pictures. To these images I have added an animation that modifies the viewing scale (x,y,z), in such a way as to obtain a pulsation effect. ("ImageEffectPingPong")
To these same images, however, I added another animation that when the image is clicked, a fade effect is obtained, in such a way as to make the image disappear.("fadeOut_x")

When I go to make transition one of the two animations to the animator, it works as it should. the problem is when I try to merge them.

The ImageEffectPingPong animation is set in loop, while the other is activated by setting a bool to the onclick event.

```
animator.SetBool($"img_{pos}",true);
```

This is my animator

[image: animator]

I tried a combination like this, but when I hit the first image, the fade works, but I no longer get the "pingpong" effect I want.

[image: test]

So how do i get the pingpong effect and when i click on an image, the fade effect, without losing the pingpong effect on the other images?

PS: to create the first effect I created a single animation that changes the scale of each image at the same time, while for the fade effect, each image has its own animation. Images can disappear following the correct sequence.
Sorry for my bad English, I hope I have explained myself as well as possible, I remain available for any misunderstandings. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone has the same problem as me, I was able to solve it by adding a layer. In the first layer I run the fade animation, while in the second the pingpong effect. It is important to set the weight of the layer.

[image: layer]